# How to filter for a Field Collection in a View

Tags: 7, views, entities, input-formats

I have a View of [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) fields. The Field Collection is composed of `field 1`and `field 2`. The Field Collection is associated, as a single field, to a content type. If I filter the View by a combination of values for **field 1** and **field 2**, and I have established a relationship with the associated content type, I can filter **combinations** of values, which come as 2-tuples; for example: **Music** and **Great Britain**, **Sports** and **USA**, etc.

However, if the View is a view of the content type, of the nodes, I don't know how to group filters in such a way that I can look for the specific combinations above. If I put two filters, and search by **Music** and **USA**, I will retrieve results even if the correct value is the 2-tuple **Music** and **Great Britain**. The view filters in ALL the Field Collections instead of just looking in one each time.

How can achieve the result with a View of content (products)? Or the way is to do it with the Field Collections, as I have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered over in [How to filter groups of paired values in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181361/how-to-filter-groups-of-paired-values-in-views/181901#181901) which appears to be essentially the same question.

Comment: Yes, I repeated because nobody answered and I was afraid that I was not being clear enough in the formulation. It seems that the problem is related to the Require relationship condition in the Views UI Relationships section. Thank you very much for your help.